# Change Rows Into Column Names Using R

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I'm trying to make column names from the rows with date. Take the following dataset, for instance:

```
# create data frame
df <- data.frame(student=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                scores=c('May, 30', 2022, 31, 39, 35))
# glimpse data
df   

  student  scores
1       A May, 30
2       B    2022
3       C      31
4       D      39
5       E      35                                                                                ​               ​        ​
```

I want to change the rows 1 and 2 from `score` column and changed them into `month_year` format and then remove the entire rows. I'm trying the following script to get the column names but getting bizarre results:

```
colnames(df) <- df[2,]
df <- df[-2,]
```

**Desired Output**

```
  student  may_2022
1       C      31
2       D      39
3       E      35
```

What would be the ideal way of getting the desired output? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your input data is very strange. Is this raw or the result of a previous treatment ? How can you distinguish between `2022` being a score or `31`?

Comment: How did you wind up with the data in the format to begin with? Doing this will still probably mess up your column classes (things will be character values rather than numeric values). It's probably better to fix this at the import step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the way your data are truly imported, as a generalizable approach you could try getting the month from the first row using `sub` and then pasting with the year from the second row.

```
names(df)[2] <- paste0(sub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", df$scores[1]), "_",df$scores[2])
df <- df[-c(1:2),]
```

Output:

```
#   student May_2022
# 3       C       31
# 4       D       39
# 5       E       35
```

Comment: Thank you @jpsmith. Much appreciated. Here both the values are in two rows. What if the date `May 30, 2022` in a single row?

Comment: if `x <- "May 30, 2022"` then a generalizable way would be:
`paste0(sub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", sub(",.*", "", x)), "_", trimws(sub(".*,", "", x)))`

Comment: Thanks @jpsmith. Can't we use `glue` and `word` from `stringr`? I tried `glue("{word(x, 1)}_{word(x, -1)}")`. Sometimes it works, sometime it doesn't