# Change Row Values Into Column Names Using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to make column names from the rows with date. Take the following dataset, for instance:

```
df <- data.frame(student=c('', '', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                scores=c('May 30, 2022', 35, 31, 39, 35))

df
  
  student    scores
1          May 30, 2022
2              35
3       C      31
4       D      39
5       E      35                                                                                ​                     ​
```

I want to change the row 1 (with date) from `scores` column and changed it into column name and then remove the entire row. I'm trying the following script (from `janitor` package) to get the column name:

```
df %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 1)

          May 30, 2022
    <chr>   <chr>
2            35
3   C        31
4   D        39
5   E        35
```

It perfectly works here. However, sometimes the date value comes separately -- broken into 2 rows.

```
student scores
<chr>   <chr>
       May, 30
        2022
C        31
D        39
E        35
```

The previous script doesn't work here. What would be the ideal way to automate the columns names from rows -- whether single row or two rows -- with a function?

**Desired Output**

```
  student  May 30, 2022
1       C      31
2       D      39
3       E      35
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this the same question? [Change Rows Into Column Names Using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787152/change-rows-into-column-names-using-r)

Comment: Hi @jpsmith. It's little different. It was more manually putting the row number based on the dataset. I am thinking if I can automate the process regardless of the dataset patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `janitor::row_to_names` approach, you can generalize this with a function:

```
df_1line <- data.frame(student=c('', '', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                 scores=c('May 30, 2022', 35, 31, 39, 35))
df_2lines <- data.frame(student=c('', '', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                  scores=c('May 30', 2022, 31, 39, 35))

ex_fun <- function(x){
  if(as.numeric(x[2,2]) > 1000){ # quick approach which assumes "true" scores < 1000
    x[1,2] <- paste(x[1:2, 2], collapse = ", ")
  } 
  x <- x %>% janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) 
  names(x)[1] <- "student"
  x[-1,]
}

ex_fun(df_1line)
#   student May 30, 2022
# 3       C           31
# 4       D           39
# 5       E           35


ex_fun(df_2lines)
#   student May 30, 2022
# 3       C           31
# 4       D           39
# 5       E           35
```

Comment: Thanks @jpsmith. It works when the date comes in two rows. However, when the date comes in a single row, it adds the next score into column too. I am thinking something that works in both the scenarios.

Comment: Gotcha @Roy - see edit and let me know if that works!

Comment: Hi @jpsmith. It works except one edge case -- when I got a dataframe where the dates are in 2 rows and the 2nd column is completely empty. It then picks only single row value. rest all good

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will be helpful.

```
  if(as.numeric(df[2,2])>1000){
      names(df)[2] <- c(paste0(df[1,2],", ",df[2,2]))
      df<- df[-1:-2,]
    }else{
      names(df)[2] <- c(paste0(df[1,2]))
      df<- df[-1,]
    }
```