# Take Dates from Row Values and Change Into Column Names Using R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

This is the extended version of the [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74877864/12210377) I'm trying to make column names from the rows with date. The problem is the dataset has mostly two patterns with one or multiple empty columns.

```
# Pattern 1: date in single row
df1 <- data.frame(student=c('', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                score1=c('', '', '', '', ''),
                score2=c('May 30, 2021', '', '31', '39', '35'),
                score3=c('June 30, 2022', '', '33', '37', '34'))
df1                                                                              ​                     ​
student   score1     score2       score3
<chr>     <chr>      <chr>        <chr>
                 May 30, 2021  June 30, 2022
B           
C                     31            33
D                     39            37
E                     35            34 

# Pattern 2: date in two rows
df2 <- data.frame(student=c('', '', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
                score1=c('', '', '', '', ''),
                score2=c('May 30,', '2021', '', '39', '35'),
                score3=c('June 30,',  '2022', '', '37', '34'))
df2

student       score1        score2       score3
<chr>          <chr>         <chr>       <chr>
                             May 30,    June 30,
                              2021       2022
C           
D                              39         37
E                              35         34
```

I want to change the row/rows with date -- sometime one row, sometime two rows -- from `score` columns and changed it into column name and then remove the entire row. @jpsmith gave a great [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74878203/12210377), which nicely works for the pattern 1, except pattern 2. It works for the pattern 2 only if the 2nd row isn't empty.

```
ex_fun <- function(x){
  if(is.na(as.numeric(x[2,2])) > 1000){
    x[1,2] <- paste(x[1:2, 2], collapse = ", ")
  } 
  x <- x %>% janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) 
  names(x)[1] <- "student"
  x[-1,]
}

ex_fun(df2)

  student           May 30,       June 30,
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>          <chr>
3   C           
4   D                39             37
5   E                35             34
```

**Desired Output**

```
    student         May 30, 2021    June 30, 2022
    <chr>   <chr>     <chr>            <chr>
3    C          
4    D                 39               37
5    E                 35               34
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this actually the 3rd time you are asking the 'same' question? I would recommend you find all the 'corner cases' first and then post a question about everything. The way you are doing it creates a lot of noise which renders the posts useless

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
names(df1)[grepl("score", names(df1))] <- ""
names(df1)[-1] <- sapply(subset(df1, !nzchar(student), select = -1), paste, collapse = " ")
df1 <- subset(df1, nzchar(student))
df1
#   student  May 30, 2021 June 30, 2022
# 2       B                            
# 3       C            31            33
# 4       D            39            37
# 5       E            35            34

names(df2)[grepl("score", names(df2))] <- ""
names(df2)[-1] <- sapply(subset(df2, !nzchar(student), select = -1), paste, collapse = " ")
df2 <- subset(df2, nzchar(student))
df2
#   student   May 30, 2021 June 30, 2022
# 3       C                             
# 4       D             39            37
# 5       E             35            34
```

Comment: Hi @r2evans. It works for most of the dataframes. However, I'm facing the same problem for the following dataframe: `df <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA, NA, "Assets", "Current assets", "Cash", 
"Accounts receivable"), X4 = c("September 30,", "2022", NA, "", 
"110,738", "358,341"), X7 = c("December 31,", "2021", NA, "", 
"149,627", "359,896")), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: It's no surprise: it has no `student` column and it has `NA`s instead of empty strings. Use `names(df)[-1] <- sapply(subset(df, is.na(X1) | !nzchar(X1), select = -1), paste, collapse = " ")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, it works with your two df.

```
  ex_fun <- function(x){
  for(i in 2:4)
  {
    if(str_detect(x[1,i],","))
    {
      if(length(str_split(x[1,i],", ")[[1]]) == 1)
        names(x)[i] = x[1,i]
      else
        names(x)[i] <- paste(x[1:2,i], collapse = " ")
    }
  }
  x[-c(1,2),]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @erik-de-luca. It works for #1. Facing the problem with #2